# How to write to Cloud SQL with Google Endpoints in Android Studio

Tags: android, mysql, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-sql

How do you access Google Cloud SQL (which is a MySQL database) with Google Endpoints in Android Studio?

I created a Cloud SQL database in the developers console and I have an android project in Android Studio. I just want to press a button and have whatever I wrote in my EditText to be written to the MySQL database. Everywhere I read on Google it says "Use Google Endpoints!" But it really provides no details on how you actually do this...

I understand Android Studio has support for all these Google Cloud Platform services but I cannot for the life of me find a tutorial or guide on how to do something so simple as I described above.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

There is a major lack in this area, I am currently trying to find answers. It helps to search generally, include examples around servelets. This is what I currently have found:

You have the options of using persistence api's such as JDA and java data objects JDO, which help make things easier, but are developed mainly for the datastore in mind so lack some functionality you might need with relational DB's, such as joins. Hibernate JPA, DataNucleus JDO/JPA, EclipseLink JPA are the main options.

[Great example wit JDO](https://github.com/jrussel1/appengine-endpoints-book-system)

JDBC is a good option for relational databases using Endpoints. Here is a tutorial(not endpoint specific unfortunately)

[JDBC example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc)

[Google docs example](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/#enable_connector_j)

Will update post as I work things out

Answer (score 0):

The other answer represents some decent sub-components of a potential answer, but I don't agree that there is really a lack in this area of connecting to Cloud SQL. Perhaps on Jul 6, '15 this might have been true, although I don't even think it was then. There is a section in the left-hand navigation of the documentation, "[Connecting to Instances](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/admin-api/libraries)" which details the various ways to connect to instances.

OP, what you need is to send a request to your API handler code, which will then open a connection with the Cloud SQL to perform any actions necessary:

```
Client code -> Endpoints code -> Cloud SQL instance
```

You can read about [Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/) in the documentation as well. It's basically a means of writing code which will run and react to a request whenever an API request comes to the back-end server you'll deploy on Google's infrastructure. These API requests are generally going to be initiated by using a client library, either in JS for the browser, or [in Java for Android](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_android), etc.